# The meaning of Euler number to a sphere

Tags: differential-geometry

According to Euler's theorem, given any polygon, the Euler number is 2. However, for a sphere, e=v-e+f=0-0+1=1, which is not 2. So, what's wrong with the whole event, since the Euler number of a sphere shall be 2 as well.

Comment: What triangulation are you considering?

Comment: To compute the Euler number of a sphere, you triangulate it first. No matter how you triangulate, you get $V - E + F = 2$.

Comment: What if I don't consider any triangulation? So, now the question turns out to be why triangulation is necessary for us to compute the Euler number.

Comment: The Euler number is only defined for triangulations on surfaces (or, more generally, for finite simplicial/CW-complexes).